# ResultSet not open. Operation GetMetaData is not allowed

Tags: java, swing, derby

I got some problem with a database class, I have got 2 methods there. That supposed to fill JTable with data from database.
The problem is Im reciving errors (tittle). Here is my code:

```
public class QueryModel {

private Connection connection = null;
private ResultSet resultSet = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private ResultSetMetaData metaData = null;

public void sendStatement(CreateDataBase database,String query)
{
    try 
    {
        connection = database.getConnection();
    } 
    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    if (!query.equals("")) 
        {
            try 
            {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

                if (statement.execute(query))
                {
                    System.out.println("Result:");
                    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Executed!");
                }
                statement.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
}

public DefaultTableModel buildTableModel() throws SQLException 
{
    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++)
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (resultSet.next()) 
    {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) 
            vector.add(resultSet.getObject(columnIndex));
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

}

The problem seems to be getMetaData function in my opinion, without this every query goes smoothly. Problems started when I added this. I haven't been using this yet, so I do not know how to handle this, don't know if there is any sence to trying fixing it instead of doing this other way. Like more manually.

Comment: are you executing the query twice?

Comment: I'm just executing it there EDIT: I mean at the time I'm calling this method it's only executed there. 
That is not the problem here I guess, without getMetaData it is working.

Comment: do you mind posting the stacktrace?

Comment: aren't you implicitly closing the first resultset when you execute the query for the second time in the "if" clause? I mean, resultset is a pointer to an object defined in the executeQuery() and then you're redefining implicitly the resultset in the execute(query). That's because you're querying twice. Try defining metadata from inside your if block and see if it works (probably will)

Comment: anyway, you should not query twice here. if you want to check if there are results or not, your if clause should be something like (if resultSet.next())

Comment: u got it, that was the if clause problem, thnx

Comment: I've added my answer officially :-) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly closing the first resultset when you execute the query for the second time in the "if" clause.

I mean, resultset is a pointer to an object defined in the executeQuery() and then you're redefining implicitly the resultset in the execute(query).

That's because you're querying twice.

Try defining metadata from inside your if block and see if it works (probably will)

Answer (score 0):

Leo is right. The MetaData object comes from the first ResultSet which is closed when you re-execute the query. Don't execute the query twice, or if you have to, make sure you get a "fresh" MetaData object from the result set which you are actually navigating.